# Raised bed for plumerias

Tags: trees

Is it wise to transplant young plumeria trees out of containers into raised bed on concrete? We want to paint the patio floor and not have to move containers.

Comment: So you are saying you will be making large 'pots' to resemble raised beds that sit on the concrete patio?  Do you not have room OFF the patio to plant your shrubs?  Plumeria is like the Rhododendron of Hawaii or tropics.  They get very large.  I'd make 'fluffed' up beds just off your patio.  How large are these raised beds?  If you do, you need to use potting soil not garden soil.  Have the bed raised off the concrete and lots of large holes for the water to drain.  No rock in that planter at all.  Please send a few pictures, thanks Kathy!

Comment: Plumerias don't tolerate frost well .

Comment: @blacksmith37  That is a certainty...where does this OP live?